# How to render 'X's and 'O's in their right squares in a Tic-Tac-Toe Game? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe Game and i reached the point i set an array of objects `players` as a state, each object in the array contains an `id` represents the id of clicked square and the player which is 'X' or 'O', but i couldn't render them on their corresponding squares, How can i use that array of objects to put the letter in the right place

```
  const Game = () => {
        //example [{id: 5, player: 'X'}, {id: 0, player; 'O'}]
        const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
        const [player, setPlayer] = useState('X')
        const [picks, setPicks] = useState([])

        const handleSquareClick = (id) => {
           !picks.includes(id) && setPicks([...picks, id])
            player === 'X' ? setPlayer('O') : setPlayer('X');
            setPlayers(players => [...players, { id, player }]) 
        }

        return (
            <div class="game">
                <ul class="squares">
                    {
                        [...Array(9)].map((_, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <Square
                                    players={players}
                                    handleSquareClick={handleSquareClick}
                                    id={idx}
                                    picks={picks}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Square = ({ players, handleSquareClick, id, picks }) => {

        return (
            <li
                className="square"
                onClick={() => handleSquareClick(id)}
            >
                {}
            </li>
        )
    }
```

I would be thankful if someone told me how to make it or what is a better way to do it from the start (a better logic)
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-brook-o1f2v?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I saw multiple things that could be fixed.

First, I'm not sure what `players` should do in the code (seems to me like a pick history) so I didnt removed it, but if not needed you can remove it. In this code it is not used (only for updating it).

Now, I changed the `picks` value to be an array of 9 which every element is a string (equals `X` or `O`), and the index to the element is the `id` of the Square clicked.
So if i clicked on Square 4 and I'm player `X`, then `picks[4]="X"`.

Now I fixed another thing. You changed the current `player` (with `setPlayer`) **before** checking if the pick was valid. Then you could get into a situation that a player shouldn't pick a square because it was already picked, and you didn't update the square, but the other player has now his turn. So, I put the `player === "X" ? setPlayer("O") : setPlayer("X");` inside the validity check of the square (`if (picks[id] === null)`).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Game />
    </div>
  );
}

const Game = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState("X");
  const [picks, setPicks] = useState(new Array(9).fill(null));

  const handleSquareClick = id => {
    setPlayers(players => [...players, { id, player }]);
    if (picks[id] === null) {
      let newArr = picks;
      newArr[id] = player;
      setPicks(newArr);
      player === "X" ? setPlayer("O") : setPlayer("X");
    }
  };
```

Finally, I passed to `Square` a new property called `squarePick` which should let the specific Sqaure know, what string to render (using the xidx`and the array of`picks`).

```
  return (
    <div class="game">
      <ul class="squares">
        {[...Array(9)].map((_, idx) => {
          return (
            <Square
              handleSquareClick={handleSquareClick}
              id={idx}
              squarePick={picks[idx]}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const Square = ({ handleSquareClick, id, squarePick }) => {
  return (
    <li className="square" onClick={() => handleSquareClick(id)}>
      {squarePick}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Hope that helped you and it was understandable.